# angularjs file upload on file select with php

Tags: php, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I wanted to upload an image after the selection without submit button.
I used [danialfarids](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) plugins from GitHub.
I suppose he made the server with `C#`, which I wanted to change to `php`. I'm having problems writing the php file handler.

This is my script files.

```
 var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

    app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
        $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                method:'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/angular/upload.php',
                data: {file: file, username: $scope.username}
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    }]);
```

And this is my html file

```
<form name="myForm"  >
<fieldset>

    <legend>Upload on file select</legend>
    <br>Photo:
    <input type="file" ngf-select="uploadPic(picFile)" ng-model="picFile" name="picFile"
           accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required
           ngf-model-invalid="errorFiles">

    <img ng-show="myForm.file.$valid" ngf-thumbnail="picFile" class="thumb">

    <br>
    <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid"
            ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit</button>

    <div class="con">
        <div class="pg" style="width:{{picFile.progress}}%"  ></p></div>
    </div>
    <p ng-bind="picFile.progress + '%'"></p>
           <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
    <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the css

```
<style>
    .thumb {
        width: 240px;
        height: 240px;
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        top: 7px;
    }
    form .progress {
        line-height: 1px;
    }
    .progress {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 300px;
    }

    .con{
        width:300px;
    }
    .pg {
        font-size: smaller;
        background: #000000;
        width:0px;
        height:1px;
    }
</style>
```

And this is the rudimentary `upload.php` (found in localhost/angular/) and I don't think it works.

```
<?php if ( !empty( $_FILES ) ) {

$tempPath = $_FILES[ 'picFile' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
$uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'picFile' ][ 'name' ];

move_uploaded_file( $tempPath, $uploadPath );

$answer = array( 'answer' => 'File transfer completed' );
$json = json_encode( $answer );

echo $json; } else {

echo 'No files'; } ?>
```

My `xampp` server is working. And I also included angular files, `angularjs`, `ng-file-upload-shim.min.js` and `ng-file-upload.min.js` from [danialfarid](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).

Comment: What is not working? Is it a 404? A 500? What does the service return, is there any output in terms of syntax errors etc?

Comment: The image is not getting uploaded .

Comment: @danial I changed the html input file  from  ngf-select="uploadPic(picFile)" to  ngf-select-"uploadPic($file)" but it is still not working. should the $file be similar to the ng-model of the input. what about the name of the input. Should it be similar too.

Comment: try using the php code in the upload module repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the answer to this question, the problem was not on the code, the problem happened because I was making **XMLHttpRequest** to a different domain than I was in. And the easy way to solve this problem is by adding extension to chrome. [Cors extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US). This solved the problem.